# which open source projects used Mylyn plugin?

Tags: mylyn

I know that by using Mylyn plug-in we can track developer's interaction with different parts of source code. In Eclipse Bug tracking system (Bugzilla) for most of the issues there is an attachment file called mylyn-context.zip which includes all the interaction history collected from Mylyn for this specific bug. I'm wondering is there any other open source projects which use Mylyn and their developers attached the same file (mylyn-context.zip) to the project's issue tracking system?

Answer (score 0):

Up till now I've never seen an attached mylyn-context.zip / issue.

When you look at projects at github, then you can connect Mylyn to the issues on GitHub. When commiting something in Git and starting with the `#issue-id` (like `#4`) and then the additional message. It is easy to see which files are most relevant for that issue, as they appear as comments under the issue.

Most scm systems have support for showing which files are effected by which issue, if the issue-id is part of the commit message. (Mostly one need to start with the issue-id in the commit message).

Answer (score 0):

Mylyn uses the context attachments (e.g., https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433030).

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.